# How to specify the order of Javascript calls?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a call to [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) and another one in [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).

I need that the order in which the Javascript is printed in the screen of the browser is just as written. What is the preference in which the content is loaded in the page? Can it be controlled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to enforce the order of your scripts, declare them as libraries via [hook_library()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) and list one as dependency for the other.